# Four-momentum, four-velocity, energy

Tags: special-relativity, momentum, velocity, vectors

If given the four-momentum of any particle monitored by an observer as:

**p** = $p^\hat{α}e_\hat{α}$ using unit vectors in observer’s reference frame and **u** = $e_\hat{0}$

then I get

[image]

I'm just wondering how the negative in front of $-p^\hat{0}$ came about. Thank you to whoever can answer me :)

Comment: What's the signature of your metric?

Comment: what do you mean signature? do you mean like what the metric equals? $ŋ_{ab} = e_\hat{a}·e_\hat{b}$

Comment: The [Metric signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_signature) is the distribution of positive and negative entries in the diagonalized metric. The are two differing conventions in relativity - namely, whether the time-like or the space-like coordinates bear a minus sign.

Comment: @Kennan You just wrote $\eta_{ab} = e_{\hat a} \cdot e_{\hat b}$.  Clearly the $p^{\hat 0}$ term comes from $p^{\hat 0} e_{\hat 0} \cdot e_{\hat 0} = p^{\hat 0} \eta_{\hat 0 \hat 0}$.  What is the value of that metric component, $\eta_{\hat 0 \hat 0}$?

Comment: oh!!! that value is -1 and that's where the negative comes in~ Thanks! :D